# Send json via POST with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I have a problem with Alamofire, i need to send a POST request with a json formatted in this way

```
{
"date":"2016/05/09"
}
```

this is my code for the request

```
static func getCalendar(date: NSDate, completion: (liveBeanList: Array<LiveBean>) -> Void){

    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)


    let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject]  = ["date": dateString]


    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/playground-server/rest/match/calendar", parameters: jsonObject, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")

            let jsonResponse = JSON as! NSDictionary
            let response = jsonResponse.objectForKey("response") as! NSDictionary;

            let match_data = response["match_data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            //let liveBean = LiveBean(fromJson: match_data![0] as NSDictionary);

            var liveBeanList: Array<LiveBean> = [];

            for match in match_data! {
                let liveBean = LiveBean(fromJson: match as NSDictionary);
                liveBeanList.append(liveBean)
            }

            completion(liveBeanList: liveBeanList)

        }
    }
}
```

but on the server arrive this string

```
data=2016%2F05%2F09
```

so it launch an exception because the string is not a json, how can i send a correct json?

Comment: The forward slash in your date is being URL encoded as %2f--probably AlamoFire is doing the encoding automatically.

Comment: @MattLong even if i remove the / and format the date in yyyyMMdd on the server the string arrive without the {

Comment: This is probably more a question related to your server technology, then. It sounds like the server is not expecting JSON. Can you see the raw request and confirm that it's not coming through with the correct JSON format?